# Access coffeescript objects or functions in another file

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have this HTML code :

```
<script src="lib.coffee"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

document.write(myCar.make)

</script>
```

and this code in the "lib.coffee" file:

```
<script type="text/coffeescript">

myCar={}
myCar.make="Ford"

document.write myCar.make

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/coffeeScript.js"> </script>
```

The code in lib.coffee works in the browser (iPad), why does not the HTML code ?
I already tried a lot of solutions found on this site, without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are organizing your code/files in the wrong way, it should be something like this.

In your main HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/coffeeScript.js"> </script>
<script src="lib.coffee"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  document.write(myCar.make)

</script>
```

In lib.coffee:

```
myCar={}
myCar.make="Ford"
```